# Using frozen mince beef

Tags: food-safety, meat, beef, ground-beef

I forgot to get my mince beef out of the freezer to cook tonight, so it's still frozen...Can I cook it straight from frozen or does it need to fully defrost?

Comment: I guess it depends on what are you going to do with it. For example, I can't imagine making burgers from it now, but I see no reason not to add it to spaghetti sauce if you can crush it...

Answer (score 1):

You can of course try to thaw it in your microwave (if you have one) or in your regular oven on low heat. However, I've never had any problems cooking with frozen ground beef. Just cook it on fairly low-medium heat and scrape off the outer layers as they get thawed. This might be easier and take a shorter amount of time if you manage to split it into smaller chunks before cooking it. Continue scraping, and splitting the big chunk into smaller parts as they thaw. If you use a low enough heat,  the parts you scraped off first won't get burnt either. 
Turn the heat up when everything is separated, and fry it. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

never try to thaw it in microwave or a regular oven. It will change the taste of the beef in a bad way as the protein would get denatured due to sudden change in temperatures.
You might actually thaw it just by keeping it under running water, it would hardly take 10-15 min.